# Why array[key] is not callable if I make sure that key === 'push'

Tags: typescript, generics

Let say I have created such function:

```js
function test<K extends keyof Array<number>>(target: Array<number>, key: K): void {
  if(key === 'push') {
    target[key](12);
  }
}
```

> [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgNKJQD1TABM1EBrFATzmEQEEAnRgQyszBAFsAjFRgHwCAFFBaMA5iigAuBszYdufQQBoK1OdgCUcgG5wYxRAG8AUIkQxgwylUQBeJ4gDkABxBoAFi+2mLlsjiUlAA2nYAusIAjABM2gDcAQC+ZslAA)

I can be sure that `target` is an **Array** and `key` can't be any string, but it has to be a keyof **Array** (for example `push`). In my example, I am checking is  `key === push` where `push`  is hinted by TS and `key` can't be any random value anymore. So, inside my if I can be sure that `target` is an **Array** and `key` is equal to `push` string literal. Why am I getting such an error? Is this an expected behavior, If yes, then why?

> This expression is not callable.
> Not all constituents of type 'number | (() => IterableIterator) | (() => { copyWithin: boolean; entries: boolean; fill: boolean; find: boolean; findIndex: boolean; keys: boolean; values: boolean; }) | ... 28 more ... | ((searchElement: number, fromIndex?: number | undefined) => boolean)' are callable.
> Type 'number' has no call signatures.

Comment: TLDR: `K` has a generic type and you currently can't narrow those. If you want this to succeed, assign `key` to a local variable with the type `keyof Array<number>` and use the local variable further down the way: https://tsplay.dev/wEBaVN

Comment: @TobiasS. I just have finished reading. This fully answers my question. thx mate